# 2016 Honda Civic. when I push on the gas it sounds like tin cans dragging? comes from front passenger side and sound stops when i take foot off gas

Tags: honda, civic

Civic makes tin can dragging sound when foot is on gas. Sound goes away when i take foot off gas. All dummy lights are on. Everyone says the turbo but it has been replaced 4x now! all good when replaced and never lasts more than 6 months. Then the noise returns in front passenger side front end under hood